# Array length issue in azure mobile services

Tags: javascript, azure, express, azure-mobile-services

I'm sending an array to the service

```
[
    {
        "toppingid": "ABB934CB-EAB7-4863-B832-7F533DA08E2F",
        "toppingname": "Default",
        "toppingprice": "0.000000"
    }
]
```

When I `console.log` it shows as above. I do console.log as below

```
   toppinglistforCart = [];
   toppinglistforCart = request.body.toppinglist

   console.log(toppinglistforCart);
```

But when I try to `toppinglistforCart.length` it returns 132 for some peculier reason.

and if I do `console.log(toppinglistforCart[0])` then it returns `[` very strange. Did someone else came through this same issue?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toppinglistforCart` variable appears to be a string, with length 132. (It doesn't work in older IE, but) JS lets you use the `topplinglistforCart[0]` syntax to access individual characters within the string, similar to how the same syntax on an array accesses individual array items.

You need to parse the JSON content of your string to create an object:

```
toppinglistforCart = JSON.parse(request.body.toppinglist);
```

Note also that your first line:

```
toppinglistforCart = [];
```

...is not needed at all - it sets `toppinglistforCart` to a new empty array but then the next line sets `toppinglistforCart` to something else so that empty array gets thrown away.